# Added accessories have no services available after adding services in HomeKit simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

So I'm trying to write a simple app to control my home kit devices, but I'm having trouble with the code.

Here is my code for browsing home kit accessories. But when I

```
print(accessory.services.count)
```

I get 0. Here is some of my code:

```
import UIKit
import HomeKit

class DiscoveryTableViewController: UITableViewController, HMAccessoryBrowserDelegate {

//outlets
@IBAction func backButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!



let homeManager = HMHomeManager()
let browser = HMAccessoryBrowser()

var accessories = [HMAccessory]()
var selectedAcc: HMAccessory?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    //setting the title to "Searching..."
    title = "Searching..."

    //setting the browser delegate = to self
    browser.delegate = self
    //searching for accessories
    browser.startSearchingForNewAccessories()

    //only searching for a short time to be efficient
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(DiscoveryTableViewController.stopSearching), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


}



func stopSearching() {
    title = "Discovered"
    browser.stopSearchingForNewAccessories()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return accessories.count

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "DiscoveryTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DiscoveryTableViewCell
    let accessory = accessories[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as HMAccessory

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.discNameLabel.text = accessory.name

    //print(accessory.services.count)

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedAcc = accessories[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDeviceDetail", sender: self)
    //performSegue(withIdentifier: "UnwindToDeviceTable", sender: self)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDeviceDetail" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? AddDeviceViewController {
            destination.addedAcc = selectedAcc
        }
    }
}


// Informs us when we've located a new accessory in the home
func accessoryBrowser(_ browser: HMAccessoryBrowser, didFindNewAccessory accessory: HMAccessory) {
    accessories.append(accessory)

    //PRINTING SERVICES.COUNT
    print(accessory.services.count)
    tableView.reloadData()
}



func accessoryBrowser(_ browser: HMAccessoryBrowser, didRemoveNewAccessory accessory: HMAccessory) {
    var index = 0
    for item in accessories {
        if item.name == accessory.name {
            accessories.remove(at: index)
            break; // done
        }
        index += 1
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}


}
```

In this class, I am browsing all my accessories. I can access all the names of all the devices, but when I print the "`services.count`", I get 0 every time. Can someone help? And yes I have added services and characteristics under each accessory in the `HomeKit` simulator.

Comment: Have you paired the accessory and added it to a home already? I'm looping services without issue after pairing and adding an accessory to a home. I am using the HomeKit Accessory Simulator with accessories I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just confirmed this, services are not available until after you add an accessory to a home, which implies that you have paired with the accessory:

```
homeManagerInstance.primaryHome?.addAccessory(accessory, completionHandler: { (error) in
   print("ACCESSORY SERVICES: \(accessory.services.count)")
})
```

If you try to check service.count before that, it does indeed come back as zero.

Comment: So I put your code in my code, and it starts the pairing process, where it brings up the menu that says "enter home kit pairing number" or whatever it says, but then it disappears and says "HomeKit can't pair with this device". Do you know what that could be? It dissapears before I have a change to enter the code

Comment: Not sure what is going on there since those screens are all magically generated and displayed by iOS. Only thought I have off the top of my head is that once that pairing screen pops up, don't click on it. Just start typing in the code.

Comment: Even when I don't type anything the screen still disappears in just a second or two. I'm confused too :/ I put your code in there too So I really don't know whats going on either haha

Comment: Do you think i could see snippets of your code? Just enough to see how you added a home and added the accessory? That would be amazing if you could